# PHP referral by link script. Is mine secure? Do you know any better ones?

Tags: php, security, session

I want to reward users if they refer a friend. I've been using the following code to do it, but I'm worried that it might not be secure (users make fake accounts to game it). Can I improve this code? Are there any other alternative scripts that do this better?

```
if (isset($_GET['refer']) || isset($_GET['r'])) {
global $database, $session;
    if (!$session->logged_in) {
        $username = mysql_safe($_GET['refer']);
        if($database->usernameTaken($username)) {
            $userip= getRealIP();

            $q="SELECT uname FROM " . TBL_USERS . " WHERE ipad = '$userip'";
                $result=mysql_query($q, $database->connection);
                $result = mysql_numrows($result);      

            if ($result == 0) {
                $_SESSION['referer'] = $username;

            }
        }
    }

    function getRealIP()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: You can start by using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` to stay clear of sql injections

Comment: What approach did you used to generate referral link?  Was it generated with a kind of random token or something?  If it is random token generated, then you should be ok because, a referral link (token) must match to the one that exist on your database.  It's almost impossible for people to guess the right referral token to match the one in your database otherwise, it'll be rejected.

Comment: I use their username. ?refer=username

Comment: I hope `mysql_safe` isn't a custom attempt at doing `mysql_real_escape_string`'s job.

Comment: One thing to note: even though you are using a set of ways to return and IP address, users who are behind a NAT may still return the same IP.  Say everyone in a particular company started referring each other.  Same IP, but you'd probably never give any credit.  I've seen code where there was a combination approach: IP address, User Agent (this CAN vary among users, but not always), Cookies, and throttling (Ie, chances are it doesn't take off SO Fast, so credit is only awareded if each request is say more than 5 mins apart).  In general, its very difficult to stop users from gaming. :-/

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Don't worry its just a shorthand method

Comment: @AaronSaray Thanks! I tried looking for a code like that, but I'm not really sure how to search for it :/

Comment: There isn't an easy "this size fits all" sort of solution for it.  However, with StackOverflow, you can come up with your own solution - and then submit it.  I recommend coming up with a solution that tracks IP, useragent, and submits cookies.  Then, try to "break it" - and when you find a way to break it, submit it to SO - and see if anyone can help you there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what level of abuse you're expecting.

Non-technically:

Are rewards transferable, are they tangible or not?  Can I just create a bunch of acounts, then use ALL of them to refer a bunch of other accounts, and reap rewards on my fake accounts and send them to my main?  If I create 20 accounts, and use each to refer once, do I wind up with 20x the rewards (spread across my fake accounts).

I can create fake accounts and log in from different places, easily.

Options: make it harder to claim the reward.  If the user just has to create an account, it's trivial.  If they have to log in and then do X, Y, and Z, it's harder to do, and you'll see less fakes.

Technically:

First off: you're relying on headers for IPs (X_FORWARDED_FOR, etc.) which can be spoofed, fairly easily.   So if you're trying to limit it to one-per-IP, this is one flaw.

Second, while you're sanitizing the username, it appears,  you do not appear to be sanitizing the IP before using it in a query.  If you're going to do manual sanitization, do it consistently, or you have gaping holes. In this case, you can spoof the IP string - I don't know what PHP will do with a bogus string, but if it doesn't barf on it,  you're asking for attacks.

Thirdly: I can come from an array of sites.  If I hard reset my DSL, I get a new IP most of the time.  I can log in from work.  I can log in from my webserver box.  All have unique IPs.  I can find proxies which may or may not actually set those fields.

You can look at other identification.  Simplest:  cookies.   Crazily more complex: things like this: https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes

Comment: thanks for the in-depth response! I ended up dropping the ip check, and only giving a refer credit if the user posts x number of times!